# Gluing hexagons to get a locally CAT(0) space

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

I believe that there are four ways to glue (all) the edges of a regular Euclidean hexagon to get a locally CAT(0) space:
[image: Gluings of a hexagon]
The first two give the torus and the Klein bottle, respectively. What are the last two? In particular, do their fundamental groups have another name? Do they have the same fundamental group?

---

EDIT: HJRW points out that I missed the several ways to glue a hexagon to get a non-orientable surface of Euler characteristic -1. I count 8 possibilities up to symmetries.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but how do you glue three edges together?

Comment: You just glue them. It's not a surface.

Comment: To follow up on the "not a surface" comment, the link of the vertex is a tetrahedron, with edge lengths of 2pi/3. Thus the shortest cycle is of length 2pi, so the link is CAT(1) and the space is locally CAT(0).

Comment: I'm certain that one of the last two must be a spine of the Gieseking manifold. See: https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1468 In any case, they should be 1-relator small-cancellation groups, so ought to be known at least to group theorists.

Comment: If you look at the standard single-relator presentations of the last two groups, the total powers of $a,b$ in the relator are $(1,1)$ and $(1,3) $. While these groups have the same abelianization, it seems plausible that they can be distinguished by their homomorphisms into the finite Heisenberg group over $\mathbb{F}_3$.This should be easily checkable by a computer algebra system.

Comment: @VictorProtsak my answer shows that the kernels of the maps to $\mathbb{Z}$ have distinct ranks, so the groups are different.

Comment: @Ian Agol: Right, and your descriptions of these groups as free-by-cyclic groups yield a lot of extra information. I am not sure what Dylan's motivations were, but  I thought of algorithmically distinguishing these groups. Then it may be useful to have a simple criterion  based on residual properties (or quotients).

Comment: My motivation was very simple: I wanted an example for my class on Metric Geometry. But then I was surprised I hadn't seen these examples.

Comment: Wait, what about the surface of Euler characteristic -1? Shouldn’t that be on your list?

Comment: @HJRW, indeed I missed those! There are several gluings that give that surface.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The third example is a spine of the [Gieseking manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gieseking_manifold). The existence of a spine of this sort follows from a result of [Iain Aitchison](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1468) and the fact that the Gieseking is make of a single regular ideal tetrahedron. I think one could get this directly from the combinatorial description, but I also checked that it's a 1-relator group that fibers with fiber with the same monodromy as the Gieseking manifold.

The group has a presentation $\langle a, b | a^2b^2a^{-1}b^{-1} \rangle$. Letting $u=ab$, we can change to a presentation $ \langle a , u | a^2ua^{-1}ua^{-1} u^{-1} \rangle$. This has abelianization $\mathbb{Z}$ with $a\to 1, u\to 0$. Hence the kernel is generated by $u_i=a^i u a^{-i}$, and the relator shows that $u_0=a(u_1 u_0)a^{-1}, u_1=au_0a^{-1}$, hence this is a free-by-cyclic group with the same monodromy as the Gieseking.

The fourth complex has fundamental group a 1-relator group $\langle a, b| a^2b^2a^{-1}b\rangle$. One may see also that this is a rank-3-free-by-cyclic group. It also has an automorphism given by $(a,b) \mapsto (a, a^{-1}ba )$. Making the substitution $u=b^3a$, one gets a presentation $\langle b,u| bub^{-3}ub^2u^{-1}\rangle$. If $u_i=b^iub^{-i}$, then one has the relations $u_0=b^{-1}(u_0 u_{-2}^{-1})b, u_{-1}=b^{-1}u_0b, u_{-2}=b^{-1}u_{-1}b$, and hence this is the mapping torus of the free group automorphism $(u_0,u_{-1},u_{-2}) \mapsto (u_0u_{-2}^{-1},u_0,u_{-1})$.

Since the ranks of the kernels of the maps to $\mathbb{Z}$ are different, the groups are not isomorphic.

I'm guessing that you can find these examples in the literature on 1-relator groups, but I'm not sure if they have names in that context.

Comment: In the fourth example, since the link of the vertex is planar, it should also thicken to a 3-manifold. Do you know which one?

Comment: @HJRW I don’t think that it thickens to be a 3-manifold, since it would then have to admit an ideal triangulation, and hence is the Gieseking.

Comment: Oh sorry, right, the relation is a *one-sided* curve on the boundary of a non-orientable handlebody.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. We might get another description of the third example from the theory of arithmetic groups: the group will be commensurable with $\mathit{PSL}(2; \mathbb{Z}[\omega])$ where $\omega^3 = 1$.

Comment: That free group automorphism is pretty simple, it looks like it should be a standard example.

Comment: @DylanThurston: A few more observations about the 4th complex (let's call it $C$). $C$ cannot be commensurable with the Gieseking complex (basically by Mostow rigidity), so the universal cover of  $C$ must be different from that of the Gieseking. In the  Gieseking case (as you observe, the normalizer of $PGL_2(\mathbb{Z}[\omega])$), there are flats corresponding to horocusps. So the flats in $C$ must have a different pattern, even though the complexes are locally equivalent.

Comment: It's easy to see that any pair of adjacent hexagons in $C$ "develop" to a unique flat (there is a unique hexagon that fits in the corner adjacent to two, since the link of the vertex is $K_4$). This pattern of flats in $C$ must be different, and presumably are stabilized by virtually $\mathbb{Z}^2$ subgroups. So I think that $C$ has "isolated flats", and is hyperbolic relative to these flats. In fact, one ought to be able to attach horoballs to the flats to obtain a $\delta$-hyperbolic space (maybe $CAT(-1)$). But there must be some branching so that it is not isometric to $\mathbb{H}^3$.

Comment: Okay, now I actually tried carrying out the development of flats, and they are obstructed (there are no complete flats). By Bridson's flat plane theorem, this implies that $\pi_1(C)$ is $\delta$-hyperbolic.

Comment: @IanAgol, how does the obstruction work? Your earlier argument that the flats exist was pretty convincing. I guess I should try it myself.

Comment: OK, I thought about it a little more: the obstruction to extending a flat is actually the same obstruction to thickening this complex to a 3-manifold. If you take a hexagon in $\widetilde{C}$ and look at a neighborhood of its boundary (outside of the hexagon), you get a Möbius strip rather than an annulus. On the one hand this is the obstruction to thickening a simple complex to a 3-manifold, and on the other hand it means that when you try to develop a flat you get some inconsistency.

Comment: Yeah, I should delete the previous comment, since I hadn't thought about the fact that development might be branched. Your interpretation make it more clear. Anyway, I wouldn't be surprised if this group is in the literature (surely it is known to Dani Wise).

Comment: Is it a coincidence that the obstruction to development is the same as the obstruction to thickening to a 3-manifold, or is this an instance of some more general fact?

Comment: @DylanThurston: Maybe what I was outlining earlier would show that if all of the hexagon flat planes are complete, then attaching horoballs gives $\mathbb{H}^3$, and hence it's commensurable with the Gieseking example.

Comment: @DylanThurston -- it's not a complete coincidence: any 2-generator, 1-relator 3-manifold group $G$ can't be hyperbolic, since $\chi(G)=0$, so the boundary of the 3-manifold would give a $\mathbb{Z}^2$ subgroup. The converse doesn't hold, of course (eg $BS(2,3)$).

Comment: @HJRW, sorry, can you spell out what you mean by "converse" (and $BS(2,3)$)?

Comment: @DylanThurston --  the "converse" I was thinking of is "non-hyperbolic implies 3-manifold" for 2-generator, 1-relator groups.  This is false because the $(2,3)$--Baumslag--Solitar group is non-hyperbolic but also not a 3-manifold group.  But there's no non-positive curvature there, so perhaps that observation isn't helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The fourth example was studied by Brady and Crisp in their CMH paper [CAT(0) and CAT(-1) dimensions of torsion-free hyperbolic groups](https://www.math.ou.edu/~nbrady/papers/cathyp2.pdf), so it would be reasonable to call its fundamental group the "Brady--Crisp group".  (Brady and Crisp also note that it belongs to a family studied by Haglund and Ballmann--Brin.)

They study a one-parameter family of CAT(0) metrics on the complex, and prove the very nice fact that any CAT(-1) model for this group has to have dimension at least 3.  (And they exhibit a 3-dimensional CAT(-1) model.)